# Output single CSS file when code splitting is enabled

Tags: javascript, bundler, code-splitting, esbuild

I would like to use esbuild to split my bundle into smaller chunks. I can do this by using the `--splitting` option, however, this also splits my CSS which results in a lot of redundant code.

Can I use esbuild's code splitting with my JavaScript, but output CSS as a single file?